# using break in an inline if statement in a loop causes a syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying this

```
while True:
    break if input() == 'q' else input()
```

This causes a syntax error

```
    break if input() == 'q' else input()
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know there are other ways of doing this but I was wondering why this didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: What is this code overall supposed to do?

Comment: People wanting to do this is pretty much exactly why Guido resisted adding conditional expressions for so long. Don't try to write idiomatic Perl in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called conditional expression and the Grammer for that is defined like [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

```
conditional_expression ::=  or_test ["if" or_test "else" expression]
```

And `or_test` is defined like this

```
or_test  ::=  and_test | or_test "or" and_test
```

And `and_test` is defined like this

```
and_test ::=  not_test | and_test "and" not_test
```

and `not_test` is defined like this

```
not_test ::=  comparison | "not" not_test
```

and `comparison` is defined like this

```
comparison    ::=  or_expr ( comp_operator or_expr )*
```

and `comp_operator` is defined like this

```
comp_operator ::=  "<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "!="
                   | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"
```

and `or_expr` is defined like  this

```
or_expr  ::=  xor_expr | or_expr "|" xor_expr
```

and `xor_expr` is defined like this

```
xor_expr ::=  and_expr | xor_expr "^" and_expr
```

and `and_expr` is defined like this

```
and_expr ::=  shift_expr | and_expr "&" shift_expr
```

and `shift_expr` is defined like this

```
shift_expr ::=  a_expr | shift_expr ( "<<" | ">>" ) a_expr
```

and `a_expr` is defined like this

```
a_expr ::=  m_expr | a_expr "+" m_expr | a_expr "-" m_expr
```

and `m_expr` is defined like this

```
m_expr ::=  u_expr | m_expr "*" u_expr | m_expr "//" u_expr | m_expr "/" u_expr
            | m_expr "%" u_expr
```

and `u_expr` is defined like this

```
u_expr ::=  power | "-" u_expr | "+" u_expr | "~" u_expr
```

and `power` is defined like this

```
power ::=  primary ["**" u_expr]
```

and `primary` is defined like this

```
primary ::=  atom | attributeref | subscription | slicing | call
```

And no where `break` statement is allowed in the grammar, that is why it is failing with compile time error.

Quoting from the docs,

> The expression `x if C else y` first evaluates the condition, `C` rather than `x`. If `C` is true, `x` is evaluated and its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and its value is returned.

So, `x` and `y` should be something which can be evaluated, but `break` is a control flow statement which cannot be evaluated.

Comment: For the love of _something_ collapse your definitions to one code block.

Answer (score 1):

[Conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) should be used with expressions, not with statements.

And, the code calls `input` twice for non-`q` input. Is that what you meant?

```
while True:
    in_ = input()
    if in_ == 'q':
        break
    # Do something with in_
```

Comment: I understand it can be done like that. What I don't understand is why I can't use `break` in an inline if statement.

Comment: @DJK, `break` is not an expression, but a statement.

Answer (score 1):

That syntax cannot be used like that. The whole `<something> if <condition> else <other thing>` thing is an expression that evaluates to some particular value, that is, is something assignable to a variable. The idea is not to put logic in `<something>` and `<other thing>`. You will have to stick with something more traditional:

```
while True:
  if input() == 'q':
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

The inline if statement - also called [conditional assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) - is python's equivalent to the tenary operator in other languages. As such it is used to assign a value to a variable based on the boolean value of an expression e.g.:

```
greeting = 'Mrs.' if person.female else 'Mr.'
```

Clearly both possible values must actually be values. This is true for all literals (1, 'string', ...), variables and function calls, but not for statements like [break](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement).

I hope this explains the WHY this is an syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep taking input until a user enters `"q"` you could use `iter`:

```
for x in iter(input,"q"):
    print (x)
```

Or just:

```
while input() != "q":
```